# How to disable Application Insight in Sitecore 9 PaaS?

Tags: app-insight

When I created my *Azure based Sitecore 9 PaaS* there were several other services which automatically installed with setup. One of which is **Azure Application Insight**  which cost around 100$ per month extra to me. I want to stop this server but could not find any option for this.

How can I stop Sitecore 9 using this possibly configuration based disable feature. Also if you can provide permanent solution it would be of more help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Locate the "Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config" in your \App-Config\Include\zzz folder, and disable it by adding ".disabled" to the end of the filename.
2. In your "ConnectionString.config" file found in \App_Config, remove the connection string for the AI instrumentation.

   > ```
   >  <add name="appinsights.instrumentationkey"
   >  connectionString="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
   > ```
3. In your \web.config file, comment out the following entries:

---

```
<httpModules>
<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
```

---

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
```

---

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="0">
    <listeners>
        <add name="myAppInsightsListener" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" />
    </listeners>
</trace>
```

---

Perform these steps on the following server roles: CM, CD

**Finally Delete the Application Insight Service in Azure to stop billing. :)**

For more information read this : 
http://integryx.net/post/2018/05/19/sitecore-9-paas-disable-application-insights

Comment: You have forgotten to add most important step - deleting the AI service in Azure :) If you won't do this, you would be still billed.

Comment: Yes Peter. Just added that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Please note there are many other places where app insights is used for logging.